# Is there any jquery selector to support round robin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there an easy way to select `next()` child in JQuery so that if current is last then next should be the first sibling?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eq` on parent element.

```
var len = $('#mySelector .child').length;
$('#mySelector .child').eq(i % len)....
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mySelector">
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/88n9w98e/

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no. However, you can check if `next()` returns anything and if not retrieve the first sibling. Something like this:

```
var $next = $el.next()
if ($next.length == 0)
    $next = $el.siblings().first();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wtj4hyct/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

```
// if current is the current DOMElement
next = current.nextSibling || current.parentNode.firstChild;
```

No jQuery needed, these are all DOM features which execute faster than any library implementation.