# Continuously flashing message on a webpage with jquery

Tags: jquery

My client has asked me to create flashing messages on his web page. I've advised against it as it's fairly tacky, but he pays the bills and he wants it so here I am...

I thought I'd just create a list of the messages and write some JQuery to make them flash all the time but there's a problem with the code below that I tried in a hurry in that recursion is excessive and the browser blocks it.

```
<div id="bannerflash">
    <ul>
        <li id="f1">Message 1</li>
        <li id="f2">Message 2</li>
        <li id="f3">Message 3</li>
        <li id="f4">Message 4</li>
        <li id="f5">Message 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $("document).ready(function() {
        $("#bannerflash ul li).hide();
        flash_banner();
    });

    function flash_banner() {
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f1").show();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f1").delay(3000).hide();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f2").show();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f2").delay(3000).hide();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f3").show();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f3").delay(3000).hide();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f4").show();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f4").delay(3000).hide();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f5").show();
        $("#bannerflash ul li#f5").delay(3000).hide();
        flash_banner();
    };
</script>
```

Yes it's ugly and now I think of it, really stupid, but every concept I can come up with for this will result in the same sort of recursion problem.

How can I dynamic flashing messages on the web page here - the smart way (if one exists)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loop over the amount of `li`s you have. Add a `setTimeout` that calls the function again and increments your loop counter.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30621258/2025923

Comment: Well, it's a recursive function with no exit condition; not sure what you expected. Can't you just use a timeout?!

Comment: @DaveNewton would you believe me if I told you I completely forgot about setTimeout()?

Comment: @Ortund Would you believe if I had a nickel for every time I forgot something about programming that I wouldn't be spending my time on Stack Overflow? :D

Comment: Yes I would haha now someone answered with this link but I can't find the answer again... It worked nicely with a bit of modification -> http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/88n9w98e/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in CSS alone, with no need for any JS code. You can define the keyframes and then apply the class to the required elements:

```css
.blink {
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -moz-animation-name: blink;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-name: blink;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@keyframes blink {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerflash">
    <ul>
        <li id="f1" class="blink">Message 1</li>
        <li id="f2" class="blink">Message 2</li>
        <li id="f3" class="blink">Message 3</li>
        <li id="f4" class="blink">Message 4</li>
        <li id="f5" class="blink">Message 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You could also put the `blink` class on the `ul` for the same effect, however I left it on the `li` as that's what element was being directly affected by your original JS code.

Comment: Next up, `<marquee>` :/

Comment: I know. OP said he already objected to the client, so I spared the lecture ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval(function, delay)`

```
 $("document).ready(function() {
    $("#bannerflash ul li").hide();
    setInterval(flash_banner, 3000);
});

function flash_banner() {
    $("#bannerflash ul li").show();
    $("#bannerflash ul li").delay(3000).hide();
    ...
}
```

This will repeatedly call `flash_banner()` every three seconds...